# ios facebook sdk revoke access premission

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I have a quiestion with iOS

How to revoke access_premission in Facebook graph api to give user ability to relogin.

Here my code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]];
NSLog(@"string = %@",string);

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"DELETE"];
[request startSynchronous];

[facebook logout];
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong.

When I try post new facebook message, I am still having Already autorizated screen

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Facebook SDK it's quite easy:

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForDeleteObject:@"me/permissions"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {}
```